# получаю ошибку при попытке прочесть json file в python

Tags: python, json

В коде python пытаюсь прочитать `JSON` файл. Получаю ошибку:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 16797: character maps to <undefined>
```

с чем это связано и как это починить?

Comment: При открытии файла указали его кодировку?

Comment: Добавьте код и полный текст ошибки в вопрос.